# Error "Missing ) after argument list" intentando pasar un valor de hora

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un error tratando de pasar un dato de hora de una base de datos, cuando intento pasarlo mediante javascript mediante jquery por alguna razón la cadena de datos se rompe y no logró entender el porque

Este es el código que estoy usando, el modo de traer los datos funciona

```
{extends file='layout/layoutTables.tpl'}
{block name="content"}
    <form class="formPaddign" id="formCaddpaquetes">
        <div class="row">

            <input type="hidden" id="Id_usuario" name="Id_usuario" value="{$idCliente}">

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4>Agenda</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label>Mostrar todos Los Resultados</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="filtro" id="tResultados"checked="checked" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label>Mostrar rango de fecha</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="filtro" id="fResultados" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-md-2">
                        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" name="datetimepicker1">
                            <input
                            type="text" 
                            class="form-control"
                            name="Fecha_inicio"
                            id="Fecha_inicio"
                            placeholder="Fecha Inicio"
                            autocomplete="off"
                            readonly="readonly"
                            />
                            <span 
                            class="input-group-addon"
                            style="cursor:pointer;"
                            onClick="$('#Fecha_inicio').dblclick();">
                                <span class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" name="datetimepicker2">
                            <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            name="Fecha_fin"
                            id="Fecha_fin"
                            placeholder="Fecha Fin"
                            autocomplete="off"
                            readonly="readonly"
                            />
                            <span 
                            class="input-group-addon" 
                            style="cursor:pointer;" 
                            onClick="$('#Fecha_fin').dblclick();">
                                <span class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- tabla agenda clientes -->
            <div class="tab-content col-md-12">
                <div 
                class="tab-pane fade show active table-responsive table-sm" 
                id="lista">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- tabla agenda clientes -->
        </div>
    </form>
{/block}

{block name="script"}
    {literal}
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('#Fecha_inicio').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
                weekStart : 0, 
                time: false,
                format : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                triggerEvent: 'dblclick',
            });

            $('#Fecha_fin').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
                weekStart : 0, 
                time: false,
                format : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                triggerEvent: 'dblclick',
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                buscarAgendaUsuario();    

                $("#tResultados").change(function(){
                buscarAgendaUsuario();              
                });

                $("#fResultados").change(function(){
                buscarAgendaUsuario();                 
                });

                $("#Fecha_inicio").change(function(){
                buscarAgendaUsuario();             
                });

                $("#Fecha_fin").change(function(){
                buscarAgendaUsuario();          
                });
            });

            function buscarAgendaUsuario(){
                var isChecked = document.getElementById('tResultados').checked;
                if(isChecked){
                    Resultados = 1;
                }else{
                    Resultados = 0;
                }
                datos = { 
                    "opcion"  : "buscarAgenda",
                    "id_usuario": $('#Id_usuario').val(),
                    "resultado":Resultados,
                    "fecha_inicio":$('#Fecha_inicio').val(),
                    "fecha_fin":$('#Fecha_fin').val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url:'../controllers/perfilClienteController.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: datos
                }).done(function(response){
                    var data = JSON.parse(response).respuesta;
                    var msj = JSON.parse(response).msj;
                    var success = JSON.parse(response).success; 
                    html=`
                    <table 
                    class="table table-bordered table-hover" 
                    id="lista">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td><strong>Dia</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Fecha</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Hora</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Clase</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Instructor</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Sede</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Sala</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Clase Online</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>`;
                    if(success){
                        var valores = eval(data);
                        for(i=0;i<valores.length;i++){
                            html+=`
                            <tr>
                                <td>${valores[i][0]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][1]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][2]}-${valores[i][3]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][4]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][5]} ${valores[i][6]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][7]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][8]}</td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-outline-success" 
                                onclick="window.location.href = '${valores[i]['url_emision']}';">
                                IR A CLASE
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-warning"
                                onclick="cancelacionAgenda(${valores[i]['id_usuario']},${valores[i]['id_clasefinal']},${valores[i]['id_paquetecliente']},${valores[i]['capacidad']},${valores[i]['fecha_clase']},${valores[i]['hora_inicio']})">
                                CANCELAR CLASE
                                </button></td>
                            </tr>`;
                        }
                        html+="</tbody></table>"
                        $("#lista").html(html);
                    }else{
                        html+=`
                        <tr><td colspan="7">${msj}</td></tr></tbody></table>`;
                        $("#lista").html(html);
                    }     
                });
            }

        //funcion de cancelacion para los clientes de la clase
        function cancelacionAgenda(
            Id_usuario = $("#Id_usuario").val(),
            Id_clase = $("#Id_clasefinal").val(),
            Id_paquetecliente = $("#Id_paquetecliente").val(),
            Capacidad = $("#Capacidad").val(),
            Fecha_clase = $("#fechaClase").val(),
            Hora_clase = $("#horaClase").val()){

            event.preventDefault();

            datos = { 
                "opcion":"cancelacionAgenda",
                Id_usuario,
                Id_clase,
                Id_paquetecliente,
                Capacidad,
                Fecha_clase,
                Hora_clase
            };

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '../controllers/clasesController.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: datos

            }).done(function(data){
                var success = JSON.parse(data).success;
                var msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;

                if(success){
                    swal("¡Realizado!", msj, "success").then((value) => {
                        alert("Se ha cancelado su clase");
                    });
                }else{
                    swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");
                }

            });   

        }
        </script>
    {/literal}
{/block}
```

Este es el codigo del Controller, la conexión a este funciona

```
public function cancelacionAgenda($datos){
    $clase = new clasesModel;

    $json = array();


    if($clase->cancelacionAgenda($datos) == true){


        $json['msj'] = 'El cliente ha cancelado tempranamente y se le devolvera su clase'; 
        $json['success'] = true;
        echo json_encode($json);

    }else{

        $json['msj'] = 'Error . No se pudo realizar la consulta'; 
        $json['success'] = false;
        echo json_encode($json);

    }
}
```

Cuando le doy click al botón de cancelar clase, este debe borrar la clase en ese día y hora, el problema es que no manda los datos bien y me tira el error que sale en el titulo. Por alguna razón, si quito la hora, se borra la clase bien pero si la pongo se rompe y no la borra. El código del modelo si funciona, el problema parece ser en el javascript o jquery
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El dato `11:00` y `2020-05-06` tienes que ponerlo como string

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese no es el error o bueno no el principal y unico...

Comment: La fecha si funciona, pero la hora es lo que da problemas

Comment: El titulo de tu post es: Error missing ") .... ese error, por el que preguntas se soluciona como te digo.

Comment: Un problema muy común de todo nuevo programador: es la falta de intentos + cerrarse a intentar algo diferente. Ánimos, paciencia, buen humor y intentar las recomendaciones :D

Comment: Coloque .toString() al lado de la fecha y no soluciono el problema

Comment: hazlo asi: "11:00" y "2020-05-05", la clave son las comillas

Comment: pruebalo en consola, el argument list (un JSON), que no sigue el formato y entiende que se tiene que cerrar. Los errores de consola son orientativos, no oraculos. Esto lo aprendes con la experiencia,

Comment: Si,  tienes razon no vi bien,  disculpa Srosle si,  creo que se soluciona como lo dijiste en el anterior comentario

Comment: Si la respuesta fue de utilidad, al costado hay un check verde para dar click, de ese modo aceptas la respuesta :D